# Unable to add Active Directory server at Pfsense User Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap, pfsense

This is being a struggle trying to add an Active Directory from Windows Server 2008 to use Authentication in an OpenVPN server in pfsense.

I have tried several times to get containers(using 'Select a container') after setting up all the info from Windows Server 2008 but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

The Base DN is the right one. I am using LDAP not LDAPS, so I have set TCP-Standard.

This is my actual config:

http://prntscr.com/eqshsw

I have also add containers by hand but using the default format of CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=local, and continue with default parameters in atributes, and add an account who have network previleges, and still nothing. It says is unable to connect to LDAP.

This is the last part of the configuration:

http://prntscr.com/eqsmnb

At status log:

```
/system_authservers.php: ERROR! ldap_get_user_ous() could not bind to server .
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting to a windows AD server, the group attrib should be "group". When I set this up, this almost has to be either the login or firewall missing a port/rule. Can you verify that your port with the AD source has a rule to allow * or you can use the windows tool ldp.exe to verify the bind process.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/252335/how-to-use-ldp.exe-to-view-entire-directory-tree-and-locate-the-microsoft-exchange-container